# MySQL Empty Result When Used Variables In The Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

This query works fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `pricing_data` 
        WHERE `Label`='BTC' 
        AND `Timestamp` LIKE '2018-01-19 00:00:%' 
        LIMIT 1" ;
```

But this doesn't:

```
$date =  date("Y-m-d ",strtotime("-1 days", time()))." 00:00:";
$to = "BTC" ; 
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `pricing_data` 
        WHERE `Label`='$to' 
        AND `Timestamp` LIKE '$date%' 
        LIMIT 1" ;
```

Any Solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you `var_dump($sql)` ?

Comment: do `var_dump($sql);` for second-one and show us what is coming.

Comment: A simple `echo $sql` shows that there are 2 spaces between the date and time i.e. `AND \`Timestamp\` LIKE '2018-01-19  00:00:%'`

Comment: http://rextester.com/WDEMUY80268 - vote to close the question as "typo"

Comment: You can include hour and minutes in the date format: `$date =  date("Y-m-d 00:00:",strtotime("-1 days", time()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is too small to look

there is an extra space in `Y-m-d`, because of which two spaces created  in DateTime you created and query didn't worked.

```
$date =  date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 days", time()))." 00:00:";
//..................^ remove space from here --------^ already have here
```

Check this output for more clarification:- https://eval.in/939013

***Note:-*** Instead of adding hours and minutes manually do with `date()` itself like below:-

https://eval.in/939015

***So finally code need to be:-***

```
$date =  date("Y-m-d 00:00:",strtotime("-1 days", time()));
$to = "BTC" ; 
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `pricing_data` 
        WHERE `Label`='$to' 
        AND `Timestamp` LIKE '$date%' 
        LIMIT 1" ;
```